# How to hack microphone driver data in user space on Windows

Tags: windows, driver

I want to hack other vendor's microphone driver data. E.g. to change the voice from man to woman.

**Solution 1:**
Record the vendor's mic data and hack the data, then stream it to a virtual microphone driver, which could be listened by all apps.

**Solution 2:**
Use APO, and below is Microsoft's official code on GitHub. You could find its APOProcess() function which is used to handle its driver data, to add delay.
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/audio/sysvad/APO/DelayAPO/DelayAPOMFX.cpp
But in this case, the APO hacks its own driver's data.

While my purpose is to hack other vendor's microphone data, whose code is not available for me. So APO is still work in this kind of case? E.g. an accessable shared memory for all vendors' microphone data?

Or any other solution?

Comment: Maybe you should use all available tools. 1. Take smartphone. 2. Install appropriate application: Voicechanger, VoiceFX, etc. 3. Pair your phone and Windows computer (by bluetooth, by aux, etc). 4. Use smartphone output as voice input. There are other hardware devices that can change voice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I want to find a solution using programming way. So that users can easily achieve the feature.